How to test a private method that creates a directory using a mocked File object?
I'm trying to test a private method that creates a directory using the File class. However, when I attempt to mock a File object to simulate its behavior, the mock is not used because the method creates a new instance of File internally. Is there a way to effectively test this private method without modifying the class, ensuring that the mock is actually used when calling mkdirs()?
private boolean directoryInitializer() {
  File directory = new File(Paths.get("some/path").toString());
  if (!directory.exists()) {
    return directory.mkdirs();
  }
  return true;
}

I can't just test the method calling it as it's the constructor.
This is what I tried:
@Test
@DisplayName("Should create the directory if it does not exist")
void testDirectorynInitializerCreatesDirectory() throws Exception {
  // GIVEN a new ClassToTest is created
  File mockDir = mock(File.class);
  when(mockDir.exists()).thenReturn(false); 
  when(mockDir.mkdirs()).thenReturn(true); 

  // WHEN
  Method directoryInitializer= ClassToTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("directoryInitializer");
  directoryInitializer.setAccessible(true);
  boolean result = (boolean) directoryInitializer.invoke(highScoreManager);
  // THEN
  assertTrue(result, "The directory should be created successfully");
  verify(mockDir).mkdirs();
}

In case it would be relevant, note that the Path is mocked with @TempDir Path tempDir in the test class.
assertTrue(result, "The directory should be created successfully"); works fine, but verify(mockDir).mkdirs(); shows that the mockDir file is never used (and I really want to know if there's a way of using it instead of the File created within directoryInitializer).

Why are you even combining Path and  File. Just use Path all the way (the equivalent methods are in java.nio.Files). Also, generally, you shouldn't be trying to mock operations like this. And the reason you mock isn't used, is because your code won't use the mock at all; it uses the File object returned by new File(...).

@MarkRotteveel For the “why” question, probably due to a lack of knowledge.
Could you say a little more about why it's not advisable to mock such operations?
I knew my mock wasn't used at all, I wanted to know if there was a way of “forcing” the use of it. Anyways, your remarks made me rethink the directoryInitializer in a better way, so many thanks !

It is very hard to do (as you already notice), and depending on how or what you're doing to mock it, you'll quickly run into all kinds of derivative problems because the code using the file or performing operations has certain expectations that your mock can't meet, or needs even more work to get to work correctly.

Add a constructor overload so that it’s possible to inject a factory (in the form of a lambda or a class) and replace the hardcoded call to new File with the factory

Thanks. It doesn't fully answer my question, but it can well serve my purpose.
